# How would I use execute_script to notify my python script

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, execute-script

So I am using Selenium in python with execute_script to detect certain html changes in a website using MutationObserver, the mutation observer is continuosly detecting the changes I need, however I do not know how to tell the python file that this change happened. Is there any way to tell the python side of the code that the change in the html happened?

Comment: what? wdym by code trials

Comment: What code have you tried by now?

Comment: I have tried logging in the console the information I need and retrieving it in python using driver.get_log('browser'), however the logs quickly accumulate and I don't want to iterate through giant lists continuously and frequently